# Left join results in extra records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

This is a basic left join problem and I have read many articles explaining what is going on but somehow the resolution is not clicking in my head. My left table has unique records. My right table has several records for each record in the left.

In the articles I have been reading this is often explained as left table has customers and right table has orders. That is very similar but not exactly what I am facing.

In my situation the left table has unique records and the right has repetitive data to be migrated into db the left table is in. So I am trying to write a query that will join on the key shared by both but I only need one record from the right. The results I am getting of course have multiple records since the single left matches multiple times on the right.

I am thinking I need to add some sort of filtering such as Top(1) but still reading / learning and wanted to get feedback / direction from the brainiacs on this list.

Here is a simple schema of what I am working with:

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE
(
Id int,
Name varchar(50),
email varchar(50)
)

INSERT @Customer VALUES(1, 'Frodo', 'frodo@middleearth.org')
INSERT @Customer VALUES(2, 'Bilbo', 'Bilbo@middleearth.org')
INSERT @Customer VALUES(3, 'Galadriel', 'Galadriel@middleearth.org')
INSERT @Customer VALUES(4, 'Arwen', 'Arwen@middleearth.org')
INSERT @Customer VALUES(5, 'Gandalf', 'Gandalf@middleearth.org')

DECLARE @CustomerJobs TABLE
(
Id int,
email varchar(50),
jobname varchar(50)
)

INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(1, 'frodo@middleearth.org', 'RingBearer')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(2, 'frodo@middleearth.org', 'RingBearer')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(3, 'frodo@middleearth.org', 'RingBearer')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(4, 'frodo@middleearth.org', 'RingBearer')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(5, 'frodo@middleearth.org', 'RingBearer')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(6, 'Bilbo@middleearth.org', 'Burglar')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(7, 'Bilbo@middleearth.org', 'Burglar')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(8, 'Bilbo@middleearth.org', 'Burglar')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(9, 'Galadriel@middleearth.org', 'MindReader')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(10, 'Arwen@middleearth.org', 'Evenstar')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(10, 'Arwen@middleearth.org', 'Evenstar')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(11, 'Gandalf@middleearth.org', 'WhiteWizard')
INSERT @CustomerJobs VALUES(12, 'Gandalf@middleearth.org', 'WhiteWizard')


SELECT 
Cust.Name,
Cust.email,
CJobs.jobname

FROM 
@Customer Cust

LEFT JOIN @CustomerJobs CJobs ON
Cjobs.email = Cust.email
```

I'm toying with row_number over partition() as maybe I should be joining to a cte with the row_number over partition instead of the table itself???

One other constraint I have is I can't delete the duplicates from the right table.

So again my apologies for the simplistic question and thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the meaning of needing only one record from the right? Which record? Or do you only care about the right table having ANY record but don't care which record? In your example they are always the same record for the same person; is that the case in all of your data?

Comment: I am only needing to add to my left db the jobname and since that is repetitive on the right I don't care which record it uses I just want it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a left join, use an outer apply... you can then use the `top` clause to limit the rows returned...

```
select
    Cust.Name
,   Cust.email
,   CJobs.jobname
from @Customer Cust
 outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from @CustomerJobs CJobs
    where Cjobs.email = Cust.email
 ) cjobs;
```

Comment: I've found in practice that this tends to be faster than row_numbers or distincts, but of course try all options to be sure since it depends on the query plan it comes up with.

Comment: I found everyone's answers to be very helpful but this one taught me something new that is the APPLY operator. From Tech Net: There are two forms of APPLY: CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY. CROSS APPLY returns only rows from the outer table that produce a result set from the table-valued function. OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns produced by the table-valued function.

Comment: Basically, cross apply is to inner join as outer apply is to left join.

Answer (score 1):

You have to come up with some artificial method of reducing the second table to one row per email. For example:

```
SELECT 
Cust.Name,
Cust.ID,
Cust.email,
CJobs.jobname

FROM 
@Customer Cust

LEFT JOIN 
(select min(id) as id,email, jobname
from
@CustomerJobs
group by email, jobname) as  CJobs ON
Cjobs.email = Cust.email
```

But that's pretty much random. Is there a way to determine which row from your CustomerJobs table is the "right" one?

Comment: AFAIK / can tell perusing the data they are truly identical so they are all right and thus I just need one....any one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Cust.Name,
Cust.email,
CJobs.jobname

FROM 
@Customer Cust

LEFT JOIN @CustomerJobs CJobs ON
Cjobs.email = Cust.email
```

The additional of the DISTINCT keyword should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
    Cust.Name,
    Cust.ID,
    Cust.email,
    CJobs.jobname
FROM @Customer Cust
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT email, jobname
    FROM @CustomerJobs) C2 ON C2.email = C.email
```

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry. Yes, group by was not needed. I believe distinct is needed, however, because there are multiple rows with the same email and job name in that table.

Comment: Yep you need one or the other - grouping by all columns and using distinct are equivalent, even in the query plan.

Comment: Good point, both ways would have accomplished the same thing. Interesting to know that the query plans are the same, too.